# Learning About Virtualization

Tags: virtualization

Does anyone know where I can start learning about server virtualization? ie: what to look for, what to avoid.

Thanks.

Comment: This is really too broad to answer properly.  Virtualization is a huge topic.

Comment: For what purpose do you wish to virtualise?

Answer (score 1):

Start from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization)